# Change power pivot data source programatically

Tags: c#, excel, datasource, powerpivot

Is it possible to change the Data Source of a PowerPivot programatically? Currently we are updating the data source manullay everytime when we are moving the reports from one server to other.

Please refer any links/ideas.
Thanks

Comment: I know this will not be possible using VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900967/use-excel-vba-to-change-powerpivot-connection-to-csv-file

Comment: any idea about this in c# ?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how that would be possible in c# either

Comment: If Power Query is an option, your could use parameters to change the data source, similar to [this](http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Article/2703/Changing-Data-Sources-in-Power-Query-with-Parameters.aspx) and use VBA or C# to update the values in the table.